# how to slice/index a df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

need to filter/eliminate the first #n row till were is present "nan" symbol from a much bigger df like df2 show.

```
main_df = {
    'Courses':["Spark","Java","Python","Go"],
    'Discount':[2000,2300,1200,2000],
    'Pappa':[np.nan,np.nan,"2","ai"],
    'Puppo':["Glob","Java","n","Godo"],
              }
index_labels2=['r1','r6','r3','r5']
df2 = pd.DataFrame(main_df,index=index_labels2)
```

I tryed with :

```
  maino_df = main_df.loc[:, (main_df.iloc [0] != np.nan) & ((main_df.iloc [0,:] < 1000))]
```

to obtain:

```
main_dfnew = {
        'Courses':["Python","Go"],
        'Discount':[1200,2000],
        'Pappa':["2","ai"],
        'Puppo':["n","Godo"],
                  }
    index_labels2=['r3','r5']
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(main_dfnew, index=index_labels2)
```

but eliminate also the columns where is nan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want to drop the first row where you have NaNs, and keep all the rows after the first row that has no NaNs?

*NB. I am assuming real NaNs here, if not first use `replace` or other method to convert to NaN, or comparison to match the data to consider invalid*

You could use:

```
df3 = df2[df2.notna().all(1).cummax()]
```

output:

```
   Courses  Discount Pappa Puppo
r3  Python      1200     2     n
r5      Go      2000    ai  Godo
```

If you just want to remove **all** the rows with NaNs, use `dropna`:

```
df3 = df2.dropna(axis=0)
```

Comment: Yes, right. .. but your code in the real df seams not working.. I obtain the same df before the function. I need normalize a df indexed by dates and eliminate those rows where beguin with NaN I can not manipulate by math funcions because are not floating point

Comment: @Simon the please provide a reproducible example

Comment: @Simon great! So which of the two variants did you end up using?

Comment: the one with .cummax()